# Params in React Router v4 is not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I know this question has been asked quite a few times and I've looked at the answers, but I haven't gone very far. I'm creating a few boilerplates (because I am tired of writing the same base code over and over again) but I can't get past RR v4; specifically, `params`.

This boilerplate is pretty simple. Right now, I am navigating to posts with RR4, however, even if I route to a post with a different slug, it always returns the same post. (`first-post`). Any advice on how to navigate properly? I think the docs are not too great where `params` are concerned. Here's the repo:

https://github.com/boilerstrapper/react-boilerstrap

UPDATE:

Here's some code:

```
components/App/index.js
// ...imports


export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Nav />

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path='/posts' component={PostList} />
        <Route exact path='/posts/:slug' component={PostListItem} />
        <Route exact path='/products' component={ProductList} />
        <Route exact path='/products/:slug' component={ProductListItem} />
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You need to include code and not just a link to code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added a little code but honestly, I'm sure someone's going to want to see context before they answer. There's no way I can add in all of that to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I actually found the answer. I wrote this in my API:

`const slug: string = req.body.slug`

Instead of:

`const slug: string = req.params.slug`

Answer (score 0):

So when you just change the param :slug in the url, you only changed whats been passed as a prop (`props.match.params.slug`) into the container component you have, but that doesn't destroy the existing component rendered and reconstruct it (since its the same one). This means the constructor isn't called again where you make your http request for the data.

To fix this, I've done similar to the following:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadEvents();
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nprops) {
    this.loadEvents(nprops.match.params.orgId);
  }
  loadEvents(orgId = this.props.match.params.orgId) {
    axios.get(`/_api/org/events?org=${orgId}`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ events: res.data });
      })
      .catch(alert);
  }
```

So that it requests the data when the parameters change!